# How do I implement checkboxes at the left of the table created with Angular 6?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material, frontend

Below is my TS file.

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { SelectionModel, DataSource } from '@angular/cdk/collections';
import { OrdersService } from '../orders.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

export interface DataTableItem {
  name: string;
  email: string;
  phone: string;
  company: {
    name: string;
  };
}

@Component({
  // tslint:disable-next-line:component-selector
  selector: 'data-table',
  templateUrl: './data-table.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./data-table.component.css']
})

export class DataTableComponent implements OnInit {

  dataSource = new UserDataSource(this.orderService);
  selection = new SelectionModel<any>(true, []);

  /** Columns displayed in the table. Columns IDs can be added, removed, or reordered. */
  displayedColumns = ['name', 'email', 'phone', 'company'];

  /** Whether the number of selected elements matches the total number of rows. */
  isAllSelected() {
    const numSelected = this.selection.selected.length;
    const numRows = this.dataSource.data.length;
    return numSelected === numRows;
  }

  /** Selects all rows if they are not all selected; otherwise clear selection. */
  masterToggle() {
    this.isAllSelected() ?
      this.selection.clear() :
      this.dataSource.data.forEach(row => this.selection.select(row));
  }

  constructor(private orderService: OrdersService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.dataSource));
  }
}

export class UserDataSource extends DataSource<any> {
  constructor(private orderService: OrdersService) {
    super();
  }

  connect(): Observable<DataTableItem[]> {
    return this.orderService.GetTestData();
  }

  disconnect() { }
}
```

I was previously able to implement checkboxes by following the example in [Angular Material Table](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview), but when I populate the table using external API, the functions `isAllSelected()` and `masterToggle()` start giving error. What should I edit to make the functions work again?

Comment: What error(s) do you get exactly?

Comment: @pschild in both functions, the `data` does not exist on type 'UserDataSource'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well for one the `DataSource` class does not have a `data` property, therefore your solution will not work. Instead of extending the `DataSource`, I would extend the `MatTableDataSource`.

If you change your data source to the following:

```
export class UserDataSource extends MatTableDataSource<any> {
  constructor(private orderService: OrdersService) {
    super();
    this.orderService.GetTestData().subscribe(d => {
      this.data = d;
    });
  }
}
```

Don't forget to import the `MatTableDataSource`:

```
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material';
```

> [Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/am-all-imports-2famx4?file=app/app.component.ts)
>   is a stackblitz that shows a working example with the
>   `MatTableDataSource`. The `pipe(delay(1500))` is just there to
>   simulate an async data request.